# how to create scroling calender tab

Tags: android

how to create scrolling tab calender so when user click on any day of week new tab will show like this image   like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZMDQ.jpg   any example or application u know which will do like this??? i want to create app which have this type calender so when user click any date   that date data will show  help me please .]

```
  DateFormat fmtDateAndTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

edtKeyword.setText( (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year);




    edtKeyword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MenuList.this, d, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

             mYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                 mMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



            selectedDate= mDay+"-"+mMonth+"-"+mYear;
            edtKeyword.setText(selectedDate);

            edtKeyword.invalidate();



        }
       });
```

Comment: how we can change the day ? like 6 to next all days ?, there is a two button to change the month

Comment: no imean is there any example or playstore app which have same tab style calender???

Comment: i just wan tto display only monday to friday in calender and its date

Comment: i don't think that you will get directly code for same there is a too alternative `one` is RnD on it and you will get some code as you want and edit as per your requirement or `Second` Start to write your own code.

Comment: ok tell me 1 more thing please w8 1 min

Comment: see this image   http://imgur.com/pXMrFmn   and this   http://imgur.com/5tp1klV  it is posisble in android to expand lis view like this?

Comment: [Expandable list](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)&[one more](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/expandable-list-in-android.html)